# Analytics Measurement Protocol - Wrong Geo

Tags: protocols, analytics, geo, measurement

```
?v=1&t=transaction&tid=UA-177611471-1&ti=2406620717&tr=79.95&pa=purchase&pr1id=2406620717&pr1nm=Initial+12-month&pr1pr=79.95&cd1=Stripe&cd2=Visa&cd3=12-month&pr1cd1=Stripe&pr1cd2=Visa&pr1cd3=12-month&pr1cd4=79.95&cid=1586819254.1603207676&uip=[USA IP HERE]&geoid=US
```

I'm sending hits to analytics using the measurement protocol, the hit I'm sending is above. We're sending from the server, but we're inserting uip with (in this case it was an American IP) and also sending geoid=US

However, this particular transaction, and many others like it, showed up as "Ukraine" (Our server isn't in Ukraine)

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `geoid` you don't need to use `uip` beacause `geoid` parameter takes precedent over any location derived from IP address, including the IP Override parameter (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#geoid).

I tried and i session hits from `US`, make sure you are looking at the same data you are sending. Alternatively, check that you are not using an active `cid` with a session detected in another location.

Anyway, you are mixing Standard Ecommerce parameters and Enhanced Ecommerce parameters when you send hit for `purchase` (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#measuring-purchases). It can probably generate inconsistencies in the data (you are using transaction but send the products with enhanced ecommerce syntax).